# How to programmatically click a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt. I have a button in the page added via the Qt Creator. It is connected to the method `void MyPage::on_startButton_clicked()`.

I want to programmatically click this button. I tried `ui->startButton->clicked()`,  it gives,

> error C2248: 'QAbstractButton::clicked' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'QAbstractButton'

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`QAbstractButton::animateClick()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#animateClick):

```
QPushButton* startButton = new QPushButton("Start");
startButton->animateClick();
```

Comment: Or use QAbstractButton::click(), without the animation.

Comment: Just one practical tip as addendum to the accepted solution: if you call `animateClick()` via signals and slots, be careful about the arguments of the signal. For example `connect(action, &QAction::triggered, button, &QPushButton::animateClick);` does not work because `triggered` sends true/false, i.e. 0 or 1 while `animateClick` accepts number of milliseconds (you will not notice 0 or 1 millisecond of animation). Therefor use lambda `connect(action, &QAction::triggered, [button](){ button->animateClick(); });`

Comment: How do you do it for a press though, not a full click?

Comment: @ISaidRollUpnSmokeAdjoint It's probably best that you post a new question for that.

Answer (score 9):

RA's answer provides the way to do it so that it's visible that the button was clicked. If all you wish for is to emit the signal, what you're doing is correct in Qt 5, where the signals are public.

The error you're facing indicates that you're using Qt 4, where the signals are not public. You can work around this by invoking the signal indirectly:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ui->startButton, "clicked");
```

This calls the method immediately, i.e. the signal will be dispatched and the slots called by the time `invokeMethod` returns. Alas, most code (mostly your code!) assumes that the signal is emitted from event processing code close to the event loop - i.e. it's not reentrant, rather than from your own code. Thus you should defer the signal emission to the event loop:

```
// Qt 5.4 & up
QTimer::singleShot(0, ui->startButton, [this]{ ui->startButton->clicked(); });
// Qt 4/5
QTimer::singleShot(0, ui->startButton, "clicked");
```

The following is a complete example for Qt 5.4 & up:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   bool clicked = {};
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QPushButton b{"Click Me"};
   QObject::connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{ clicked = true; qDebug() << "clicked"; });
   Q_ASSERT(!clicked);
   b.clicked(); // immediate call
   Q_ASSERT(clicked);
   clicked = {};
   // will be invoked second - i.e. in connect order
   QObject::connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, &app, &QApplication::quit);
   QTimer::singleShot(0, &b, [&]{ b.clicked(); }); // deferred call
   Q_ASSERT(!clicked);
   app.exec();
   Q_ASSERT(clicked);       
}
```

Comment: It didn't wok in Qt 5.7.0.

Comment: @HAßdøµ It certainly does work, a lot of Qt would be broken if it didn't. If it doesn't work for you, please ask a new question. I've included an example that demonstrates how to test it.

Comment: for me fails with 

QObject::connect: Use the SLOT or SIGNAL macro to connect QPushButton::clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the animation stuff, you can also just call the method:

```
on_startButton_clicked();
```